# Total number of count in entire data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a　pandas data frame with 10*5, as shown in the fig
[image]

the numbers in this vary from 1-10

I need to count the total number of occurrences of each number.
Please note that it should find the entire data frame, not just an individual column

Eg:

number (1) appears : 3 times

number (2) appears : 7 times

number (3) appears : 5 times

number (4) appears : 0 times

number (5) appears : 6 times

number (6) appears : 8 times

number (7) appears : 7 times

number (8) appears : 5 times

number (9) appears : 6 times

number (10) appears : 3 times

Note: Data frame shown here is just an example,
numbers may vary to  from 1 to 30.

Please guide me. Many thanks in advance.

I just started coding in python and using pandas on my own and I admit I am a bit lost.

Thanks for reading all this and thanks in advance for any suggestions and feedback. ! If further information is required , please leave your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series` and then count values by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for add also missing values, last for custom ouput is possible use loop with `print`:

```
np.random.seed(123)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,5)))

s = df.stack()
out = s.value_counts().reindex(range(0, 11), fill_value=0)
print (out)
0     5
1     4
2     3
3     3
4     3
5     0
6     2
7     2
8     0
9     3
10    0
dtype: int64

for k, v in out.items():
    print(f'number ({k}) appears : {v} times')

number (0) appears : 5 times
number (1) appears : 4 times
number (2) appears : 3 times
number (3) appears : 3 times
number (4) appears : 3 times
number (5) appears : 0 times
number (6) appears : 2 times
number (7) appears : 2 times
number (8) appears : 0 times
number (9) appears : 3 times
number (10) appears : 0 times
```

Or:

```
print (out.reset_index().apply(lambda x: f'number ({x["index"]}) appears : {x[0]} times', axis=1))
0      number (0) appears : 5 times
1      number (1) appears : 4 times
2      number (2) appears : 3 times
3      number (3) appears : 3 times
4      number (4) appears : 3 times
5      number (5) appears : 0 times
6      number (6) appears : 2 times
7      number (7) appears : 2 times
8      number (8) appears : 0 times
9      number (9) appears : 3 times
10    number (10) appears : 0 times
dtype: object
```